# Sqlite how to improve performance?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to make more than 300 selects from my database.
Each of those queries has to be called inside of a for each loop, here's an example:

```
for(int id : myids){
    Cursor cursor = MyDatabaseHelper.runMyQuery(id);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        //my stuff...
    }
}
```

MyDatabaseHelper is an instance of a database helper class, the function is like this

```
public Cursor runMyQuery(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor ret = db.rawQuery("select Name, Surname, Age from PTable where Id = " + id, null);
    return ret;
}
```

I've been told that the constant "open and close" of the db because of multiple queries it the cause of my performance issues and I should, instead, make a single query (using union etc).
Changing my code to a single query would mean changing the entire database, and I was hoping not to do that.

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance and keep the multiple selects at the same time?
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can return a single `Cursor` containing all the rows.
First change your `runMyQuery()` method to this:

```
public Cursor runAll(String list){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "select Name, Surname, Age from PTable where " + list + " like '%,' || id || ',%'"
    Cursor ret = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    return ret;
}
```

So you pass to the method `runAll()` a String which is the the comma separated list of all the `id`s that you have in `myids` and with th eoperator `LIKE` you compare it to each `id` of the table.
You create this list and get the results in a `Cursor` object like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(",");
for(int id : myids){
    sb.append(String.valueOf(id)).append(",");
}
String list = sb.length() > 1 ? sb.toString() : "";

if (list.length() > 0) {
    Cursor c = runAll(list);
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        //your stuff...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the in clause.

Convert your myids into a string. Something like

```
String inClause = "(1,2,3)"
```

and you can use it as

```
"select Name, Surname, Age from PTable where Id in " + inClause
```

You can read more of the in operator [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-in/)